# Backing up thousands of images in PHP?

Tags: php, zip, backup

I am just currently wondering how I can backup a folder which contains 8000+ images without the script timing out, the folder in all contains around 1.5gb of data, which we need to backup ourselves every so often.

I have tried the zip functionality provided in PHP, however it simply times out the request due to the huge number of files needed to be backed up, it does however work with smaller amounts of work.

I am trying to run this script through a HTTP REQUEST, would putting it through a Cronjob ignore the timeout?

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Have you considered chopping up task into several script calls instead of backing up all files at once?

Comment: Yes I was considering that, as all of the files are logged into a MySQL database I was thinking of chopping them up 500 files at a time to be run every 5 minutes. It seems like a logical idea, and one that wont get me in trouble with the host it seems. I believe with PHP Zip functionality I can reopen a previously made zip yes?

Comment: You can change the timeout for that one script: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use php for that.

If you are on linux I would setup a cron job and to run a program like rsync periodically.

A nice [introduction about rsync](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html).

**Edit:** If you do want / need to go the php way, you can also consider just copying instead of using zip. `zip` normally doesn't do much with images and if you have a database already, you can check your current directory against the database and just do a differential backup (just copy the new files). That way only your initial backup would take a long time.

Comment: Hello @jeroen, I am on a shared hosting environment, and I am unsure as to whether I can use rsync on shared hosting? If I can that would be awesome because we would like to start backing up the images as our host doesn't back them up themselves very regularly.

Comment: @Jake Ball Do you have shell access? If so, a simple `rsync --version` will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: yes we have shell access, although I don't think rsync is what I am looking for. From what I understand, you use rsync to essentially "mirror" files from one server to another, we are looking at moving a backup of files to our shared dropbox account, so we always have a backup of the images should it ever come to needing them. I already have the Dropbox link set up, however I was thinking that zipping them up would mean I am not sending so many requests to dropbox, however it seems individual files is the way to go for "differential" backups.

Answer (score 0):

You can post the code so we can optimize it, other than that, you should change your php.ini (configuration file) and remove/increase the timeout (the longest time your script can run on your server)